# Не удается выделить место для подкачки. Storage VPS

Tags: centos, vps, swap

Третьи сутки сижу, в линукс новичок и совсем не понимаю что к чему.

Заказал Storage VPS, необходим только для хранения и отдачи файлов по протоколу http. Чтобы поддерживал огромное количество одновременных соединений.

Для этого установил nginx, настроил, отлично. В процессе выяснилось что, что не используется диск, исключительно оперативная память.

Далее как я понял, необходимо было настроить swap. В процессе выяснилось

```
sudo mkswap /root/swapfile
mkswap: /root/swapfile: warning: wiping old swap signature.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 204799996 KiB
no label, UUID=fa13847d-3681-4a1a-91eb-714a95935bc2
sudo swapon /root/swapfile
swapon: /root/swapfile: swapon failed: Operation not permitted
```

То есть это особенность сервера. swap файл недопустимо использовать как я понял.

Тогд вопрос. Как настроить таким образом, чтобы все работало? Чтобы диск 250gb использовался, а не исключительно 512мб оперативной памяти.

```
top
top - 12:11:01 up 10:10,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:  33 total,   1 running,  32 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :   524288 total,        0 free,    27628 used,   496660 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   412418 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    1 root      20   0   43228   2992   1912 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.82 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/1333
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/1333
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/0
    5 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/1
    6 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/2
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/3
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/4
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/1333/5
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nfsiod/1333
  101 root      20   0   41572   1392    940 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 systemd-udevd
  107 root      20   0   39052   3072   2784 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.62 systemd-journal
  138 dbus      20   0   58044   1940   1444 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.76 dbus-daemon
  139 root      20   0   26336   1596   1324 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.35 systemd-logind
  145 root      20   0   22692   1512    900 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.04 crond
  438 root      20   0  112888   2384   1356 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.11 sshd
  445 root      20   0    6468    764    640 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 agetty
  446 root      20   0    6468    768    640 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 agetty
  450 root      20   0  171008   2144    176 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 nginx
  452 nginx     20   0  171448   3116    712 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.01 nginx
  453 nginx     20   0  171180   2564    376 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.16 nginx
 1543 root      20   0  155480   6496   5116 S  0.0  1.2   0:00.09 sshd
 1545 root      20   0   72240   2944   2132 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.00 sftp-server
 1559 root      20   0  155480   6500   5116 S  0.0  1.2   0:00.08 sshd
 1561 root      20   0   72240   2940   2132 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.01 sftp-server
 1616 root      20   0  155480   6508   5128 S  0.0  1.2   0:00.10 sshd
 1618 root      20   0   11780   1912   1512 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.01 bash
 1656 root      20   0   72572   2404   1524 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 crond
 1657 root      20   0    9516   1360   1172 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 run-parts
 1659 root      20   0    4316    544    456 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sleep
 1669 root      20   0  155480   6508   5128 S  0.0  1.2   0:00.10 sshd
 1671 root      20   0   11780   1916   1516 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.02 bash
 1737 root      20   0   56136   2164   1508 R  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 top
```

Как быть, возможно мне не стоило ни апатч, ни nginx устанавливать, а применить что та другое?

Не понимаю, очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Любая оптимизация делается в таком порядке: сначала выявляем проблему, что памяти действительно нехватает, потому решаем.

Какие у вас свидетельства того, что памяти не хватает?

Comment: KiB Swap:        0 total

Comment: Где 240гб? Оперативная память загружается и все на этом, затем сайт просто перестает отдавать файлы

Comment: Что показывает top когда "сайт перестает отдавать файлы"?
"огромное количество одновременных соединений" и "512 мегабайт памяти" - взаимоисключающие вещи

Comment: по сути вопроса (отражённой в заголовке): [openvz не позволяет использовать «внутри-vm-ный» swap, только общесистемный](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2893/110559). // *Как быть, возможно мне не стоило ни апатч, ни nginx устанавливать* — если вам **действительно** требуются манипуляции со swap-ом, то не следовало выбирать хостинг с openvz. // а вопрос вообще очень похож на «проблему молотка».